# Doesnt iterate over the file?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to find the line in the outfile (of) that starts with the letters ATOM and then do something with it but unfortunately it doesn't iterate over the file. Does anybody knows why?

```
with open(args.infile, "r") as f, open(args.outfile, "w+") as of, open(args.reference,"r") as rf:
    for line in f:
        of.write(line)
    for line in rf:
        if line[0:3]== "TER":
            resnum = line[22:27]
            #resnum_1[resnum] = "TER"
    for line in of:
        if line [0:4]== "ATOM":
            res = line[22:27]
            if res == resnum:
                print res
```

Comment: You have all the files open at the same time. Have you tried opening `of` in a different block than the one in which you write to it?

Comment: Why do you have `of` at all? It looks like you could just use `f` directly.

Comment: 1) you're iterating over the entire contents of rf but only grabbing the last line that starts with `TER`, do you want a break or some more complex logic here?; 2) `of` is equal to `f`, so you could just use `f` directly (and copy the contents of `f` to `of` somewhere else)

Comment: Yes but then it doesnt write all the lines from the f file into the of file if I close it.

Comment: user2357112: No, I need the original file as well.

Comment: @Loki: But `of` is going to have identical contents to `f`.

Comment: i will do to it something after. I havent got there yet in the code.

Comment: Outside of this debate, does one of the answers given solve your problem? All of your questions are currently open. If something posted in the answers fits the bill, you should [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that everyone knows the question is closed (and you get some reputation too).

Comment: @Loki rather than doing something to it after, why not do `for line in f: line  = do_something(line); if line.startswith('ATOM'):...` (You should be using `.startswith` anyway, btw)

Comment: I will do, sorry

Comment: Wayne: yes, I should. But it will take me a long time to figure out how so I am just doing the code bit by bit at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel's answer gave you the correct reason, but wrong advice.

You want to flush the data to disk, then move the pointer to the beginning of the file:

```
# If you're using Python2, this needs to be your first line:
from __future__ import print_function

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for num in range(1000):
        print(num, file=f)
    f.flush()
    f.seek(0)
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Just add `of.flush(); of.seek(0)` before `for line in of`, and you'll do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

There is a file pointer, that points to to last position written or read. After writing to `of`, the file pointer is at the end of the file, and therefore cannot read anything.

Best, open the file twice, once for writing and once for reading:

```
with open(args.infile, "r") as f, open(args.outfile, "w") as of:
    for line in f:
        of.write(line)

with open(args.reference,"r") as rf:
    for line in rf:
        if line[0:3]== "TER":
            resnum = line[22:27]
            #resnum_1[resnum] = "TER"

with open(args.outfile, "r") as of
    for line in of:
        if line [0:4]== "ATOM":
            res = line[22:27]
            if res == resnum:
                print res
```

Answer (score 1):

After the first loop, the file point of `of` points after the last line you wrote. When you try to read from there, you're already at the end of the file, so there's nothing to loop over. You need to seek back to the beginning.

```
with open(args.infile, "r") as f, open(args.outfile, "w+") as of, open(args.reference,"r") as rf:
    for line in f:
        of.write(line)
    for line in rf:
        if line[0:3]== "TER":
            resnum = line[22:27]
            #resnum_1[resnum] = "TER"
    of.seek(0)
    for line in of:
        if line [0:4]== "ATOM":
            res = line[22:27]
            if res == resnum:
                print res
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers offered some insight, but I like clean / short code and the complications of flushing / seeking aren't really required:

```
resnum = ''
with open(args.reference,"r") as reffh:
    for line in reffh:
        if line.startswith("TER"):
            resnum = line[22:27]

with open(args.infile, "r") as infh, open(args.outfile, "r") as outfh
    for line in infh:
        outfh.write(line) # moved from the first block

        if line.startswith("ATOM"):
            res = line[22:27]
            if res == resnum:
                print res
```